# How do you leverage your bitcoins?

Tags: trading

I was previously putting my bitcoins into btcjam, but as there are no longer any secured loans I was thinking about moving my bitcoins into something else that will generate some profit over time while keeping the bitcoins in circulation. Coinlenders.com looked promising except for

```
 This is a demo instance of the CoinLenders Bitcoin Bank Script. While this demo is fully functional, nothing is real, and nothing is an investment.
```

What have you been doing with your bitcoins other than spending them?

I would like something that is low effort, low risk. Low return is fine; I was planning on sitting on most of my bitcoins anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I co-founded [Bitbond.net](https://www.bitbond.net) for purposes like yours. It's a peer to peer lending website where you can earn interest on your Bitcoins. However, the loans are unsecured and you need to decide which projects you like to lend to.

One of the reasons we had and still have a financial crisis is because many people did not really care what other people were doing with their money. Then they found out that some of the banks they trusted put their money to work in products the bankers didn't even understand themselves.

Low effort is always a double-edged sword as it might create much more work later.

Answer (score 1):

ButterBot:
https://butter-bot.com/?r=c0de83b9

This is an automated trading bot I use that makes over 3400% profit (over 2 years) on your choice of 3 different exchanges. It's reasonably priced & has excellent support. I highly recommend it. It was easy for me to learn.